# Selecting a class within a used defs/symbol

Tags: css, svg, symbols

I'm trying to alter the colours of a multi-element `defs`, based on the enclosing CSS class. So far I've had zero success. I started out using a `symbol`, then changed it to a `defs` with a `g` in it.

I've put together an example codepen: [addressing a class within a `defs`](https://codepen.io/alfred3x/pen/PoEOQxQ) The square on the right should be green on top and yellow on the bottom.

```css
.rect1 { fill: red; }
.rect2 { fill: yellow; }
.morph .rect1 { fill: green; }

rect { stroke: black; }
svg { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <g id="house-def">
      <rect class="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="10" />
      <rect class="rect2" x="10" y="20" width="20" height="10" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#house-def" />
  <use xlink:href="#house-def" class="morph" transform="translate(30)" />
  
</svg>
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the color of the rect1 change the fill of the use elements:

```css
use{ fill: red; }/*will fill red both use elements*/
.rect2 { fill: yellow; }/*will fill yellow the .rect2 inside defs*/
.morph { fill: green; }/*will fill green the second use element overwritting the fill:red from the first roule.*/

rect { stroke: black; }
svg { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <g id="house-def">
      <rect class="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="10" />
      <rect class="rect2" x="10" y="20" width="20" height="10" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use class="a" xlink:href="#house-def" />
  <use xlink:href="#house-def" class="morph" transform="translate(30)" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you, that works. Instead of using the `use` tag, I used the `.a` class, and that still worked. I'm trying to get my head around why it works. And why my original didn't work. Any hints welcomed.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the colours of two elements within the `use`?

Comment: This would be a different question. Ask a question and add a code example. I'll be glad to help.